Laptop lid close not reacted to
Problem: After updating to Ubuntu 22.04 my laptop lid close/open doesn't seem to be detected, when I close the lid nothing happens and the screen remains on.
What has been looked at: After reading a lot of related posts, I can at least see some of what needs to be checked.  Unfortunately, I'm quite unqualified to work out how to resolve the issue, and the posts I've found don't shed much light.  The contents of /etc/systemd/logind.conf are set to react to the lid closing:
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes

Moreover there's no obstruction from UPower:
$ grep -i lid /etc/UPower/UPower.conf 
# Do we ignore the lid state
# Some laptops are broken. The lid state is either inverted, or stuck
IgnoreLid=false
# If any value is invalid, or not in descending order, the defaults
# If any value is invalid, or not in descending order, the defaults

However, still no reaction when I open and close the lid.  In fact, there is no record in the log that the action of opening/closing is detected.  That is, (truncating the output to the last 10 minutes) I get
$ journalctl | grep -i " lid "
Aug 23 21:38:30 MACHINE /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2056]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
Aug 23 21:49:25 MACHINE /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2118]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)

However the action is being detected by acpi:
$ acpi_listen 
button/lid LID close
button/lid LID open

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Is this a recently released model? If so, can you try 24.04 (which would have better support for newer version of Ubuntu)

The machine is at least 3 years old, and worked fine on 18.04 before I updated. Is there any reason to expect 22.04 to be less compatible than 18.04? I’m loathe to upgrade to 24.04 since it’s still so new, and I’m already having issues with its predecessor.
